# Discriminant Analyses in R using ade4

Tags: r

I am trying to run a discriminant analysis to identify variables that separate different populations and season. I have 5 estimated continuous variables which i am using to identify the separation between these populations and seasons.

My factor variables are season and SITE. My continuous variables are calcNDVI, meanNDVI, maxNDVI, minNDVI, cvNDVI, diffNDVIvals.

```
head(df)

     X      x      y       date     dx     dy      dist    dt       R2n abs.angle
3 6677 15.380 52.210 2010-08-12  1.960 -5.900 6.2170411 86400  16.95890 -1.250063
4 6678 17.340 46.310 2010-08-13 -3.300 -0.900 3.4205263 86400 105.41690 -2.875341
5 6679 14.040 45.410 2010-08-14 -1.980 -0.055 1.9807637 86400 106.77890 -3.113822
6 6680 12.060 45.355 2010-08-15 -0.495  0.675 0.8370484 86400 108.54852  2.203545
7 6681 11.565 46.030 2010-08-16 -0.360  0.105 0.3750000 86400  96.40842  2.857799
8 6682 11.205 46.135 2010-08-17 -0.245 -0.485 0.5433691 86400  95.70065 -2.038559

    rel.angle           id        burst         SITE COUNTRY year month     newDate
3 -0.02783079 21333_A31271 21333_A31271 SOUTH.SWEDEN  SWEDEN 2010     8 X2010.08.12
4 -1.62527754 21333_A31271 21333_A31271 SOUTH.SWEDEN  SWEDEN 2010     8 X2010.08.13
5 -0.23848141 21333_A31271 21333_A31271 SOUTH.SWEDEN  SWEDEN 2010     8 X2010.08.14
6 -0.96581813 21333_A31271 21333_A31271 SOUTH.SWEDEN  SWEDEN 2010     8 X2010.08.15
7  0.65425338 21333_A31271 21333_A31271 SOUTH.SWEDEN  SWEDEN 2010     8 X2010.08.16
8  1.38682762 21333_A31271 21333_A31271 SOUTH.SWEDEN  SWEDEN 2010     8 X2010.08.17

   calcNDVI meanNDVI maxNDVI minNDVI   cvNDVI diffNDVIvals yDay    seas
3 7542.487 6296.268    8399     978 20.82924         7421  224 Aug-Sep
4 5018.169 5906.929    7908    3181 22.97476         4727  225 Aug-Sep
5 7513.909 6390.036    8172    3803 22.54474         4369  226 Aug-Sep
6 5763.429 4564.911    7120    2456 25.60007         4664  227 Aug-Sep
7 6161.736 6115.429    8052    1217 25.97495         6835  228 Aug-Sep
8 7995.656 6207.036    7852    2191 20.11494         5661  229 Aug-Sep
```

As far as i know my variables are in correct format i.e numeric and factors. 
now when i run a DA using ade4 package, i get an error which i am not sure what it means:

```
df.pca=dudi.pca(df[,19:24],scan=F)

df.dis=discrimin(df.pca,interaction(df$SITE,df$seas),scan=F)

Error in if (any(row.w < 0)) stop("row weight < 0") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

First i thought it is probably because of NAs, but its not. 
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replicated the error with `mtcars`since you didn't provide a `dput` output, and pasting from the clipboard didn't work:

```
> df = mtcars
> df.pca = dudi.pca(df,scannf=F)
> df.disc = discrimin(dudi=df.pca,interaction(df$carb,df$cyl),scan=F)
```

Gives:

```
Error in if (any(row.w < 0)) stop("row weight < 0") : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

However, a little tweak fixed the problem: I just specified the `fac` option and made it into `factor`, even though `str(interaction(df$carb,df$cyl))`returns a `factor`.

```
df.disc = discrimin(dudi=df.pca,fac=factor(interaction(df$carb,df$cyl)),scan=F)
```

Returns no errors

Comment: @navindersingh, Glad to be able to help! Just a tip on using `Stackoverflow`, but if your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references.